# Listener on PieChart animation ending in MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I'm using [MPAndroidChart](http://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library for doing `PieChart` animation. I'm trying to find the way to listen for callbacks upon `PieChart`(or any) animation ending (and it's started by invocation the `animateY(int durationMillis)` method before). [Official documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart) doesn't offer any listeners for this purpose. Does anyone have any ideas how to do it?

Thanks in advance!